# open specific part of table of contents of chm file c# or vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, chm

I have a .chm file called help, In that file I have a structure like:

```
Introduction
  -item1
  -item2
Topic1
  -item1
  -item2
Topic2
  -item1
  -item2
Topic3
```

Now I want to open Topic1 inside c# or vb.net I have tried:

```
 Help.ShowHelp(ParentForm, "Help.chm", HelpNavigator.Index, "Topic1")
 Help.ShowHelp(ParentForm, "Help.chm", HelpNavigator.TableOfContents, "Topic1")
 Help.ShowHelp(ParentForm, "Help.chm", HelpNavigator.Topic, "Topic1")
 Help.ShowHelp(ParentForm, "Help.chm", HelpNavigator.KeywordIndex, "Topic1")
```

but is not working, then I tried to give inside chm file an index to Topic1 (31) and tried:

```
 Help.ShowHelp(ParentForm, "Help.chm", HelpNavigator.Index, "31")
 Help.ShowHelp(ParentForm, "Help.chm", HelpNavigator.Index, "Item1")
```

It gives execption, only working code is:

```
 Help.ShowHelp(ParentForm, "Help.chm", HelpNavigator.TableOfContents, Nothing)
```

How to open Topic1 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> You can use the param parameter to provide further refinement of the
>   Topic, TopicId, KeywordIndex, or AssociateIndex command. If the value
>   specified in the command parameter is TableOfContents, Index, or Find,
>   this value should be an empty string. If the command parameter
>   references Topic, TopicId, KeywordIndex, or AssociateIndex, this value
>   should be a string that contains the topic name, or the keyword or
>   numeric identifier of the topic to display.

So answer was to do:

```
Help.ShowHelp(ParentForm, "helpFile.chm", "topicURL.htm")
```

The topicURL Found  right clicking on opened topic:

[image]

then copy url:

[image]